# Giving counterexample to statements about Quotient Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $H_i \trianglelefteq G_i$ for $i = 1, 2$.

Obs.: all statements below are *false*

(a) If $H$ and $G/H$ is abelian, then G is abelian.

(b) If every proper $H$ of $G$ is cyclic, $G$ is cyclic.

(c) If $G_1 \cong G_2 $ and $H_1 \cong H_2$ $\Rightarrow$ $G_1/H_1 \cong G_2/H_2$.

(d) If $G_1 \cong G_2 $ and $G_1/H_1 \cong G_2/H_2 \Rightarrow H_1 \cong H_2$.

(e) If $H_1 \cong H_2 $ and $G_1/H_1 \cong G_2/H_2 \Rightarrow G_1 \cong G_2$.

I think this question is very relevant to understand the structure of groups, and I have been trying to (a), and it just seems that I want to be clear if G/H has the identity element. And also I want a clear definition of what does it mean for a group to be isomorphic in the above cases, and examples would just be a way to comprehend better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hints:*

(a) Take a non-Abelian group $G$ with an Abelian subgroup $H$ of index $2$. The smallest example will work.

(b) Consider a group of order $4$.

(c) Consider $G_1 = G_2 = \mathbb Z/2 \times \mathbb Z/4$.

(d) See (c).

(e) Consider $G_1 = D_4$, the dihedral group of order $8$ and $H_1$ the center of $G_1$. Then consider $G_2 = \mathbb Z/2 \times \mathbb Z/4$. (There is also an example where $G_1, G_2$ have order $6$.)

Comment: The thing I don't understand well is how a quotient group is formed also, can you show me a construction method?

Comment: What do you mean by "construction method"? Do you mean how one comes up with counterexamples like these? I guess it's just experience and going through examples of small groups.